# Slow Update in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, updates, query-performance

Trying to update a column in a 4.4 million rows table. I have been able to reduce my query time from 30+ minutes to 14 minutes with the following version:

```
update t_settlement x
    set dt_ad_decode = y.decode
    from (Select dt_amountdescription_1to1, dt_decode as decode
          from d_amountdescription_1to1
         ) y
    where x."AmountDescription" = y.dt_amountdescription_1to1;
```

I am sure there must be ways to improve this further and would be grateful if somebody could help me in this regards.

Regards

Saurabh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why are you using a subquery?  Write this more simply as:

```
update t_settlement s
    set dt_ad_decode = ad.dt_decode
    from d_amountdescription_1to1 ad
    where s."AmountDescription" = ad.dt_amountdescription_1to1;
```

This shouldn't affect performance, but it simplifies the query.

Next, you want an index on `d_amountdescription_1to1(dt_amountdescription_1to1)` or, better yet, `d_amountdescription_1to1(dt_amountdescription_1to1, dt_decode)`:

```
create index idx_d_amountdescription_1to1_2
    on d_amountdescription_1to1(dt_amountdescription_1to1, dt_decode)
```

Comment: The reason i did it in a sub-query was that the query took ~3 minutes lesser than the query updated above. Another Question, will this index boost performance.

Comment: @SaurabhOmar . . . Seems odd.  You an check the execution plans, but I would expect the subquery to be optimized away.  The index should improve performance beyond that.